# how to use Partition wise join in case of hash partition tables

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have two large tables ,both of which are partitioned by hash partitioned and partitioned on  same partition key column,and have same number of partitions.
But I have an issue here ,I am difference in count in below two cases (ideally the counts should be equal in both cases)

```
1)
select count (1) from tab1 t1,tab t2
Where t1.k = t2.k

2)
select count(1) from tab1 partition (t1_p1) t1,tab2 partition(t2_p1) t2 where t1.k=t2.k;
select count(1) from tab1 partition (t1_p2) t1,tab2 partition(t2_p2) t2 where t1.k=t2.k;
select count(1) from tab1 partition (t1_p3) t1,tab2 partition(t2_p3) t2 where t1.k=t2.k;
```

There 8 partitions like this in the second case .
Ideally since it's the same data in both cases above the counts in the first case and the sum of all counts in second case should be equal,but they are not equal .
What am I doing wrong here ? Is my expectation that all values present in first partition of t1 table should be there in first partition of table 2 ,and all values of second partition of first table match with values of second partition in second table wrong?

Comment: Is `k` unique for each row?

Comment: Basically the queries return the correct results according to the data. You can take that to the bank. So if the results don't match your expectation that points to a discrepancy between the actual data and your understanding of it. You need to write some diagnostic queries which will give you insight into the real state of the data. Alex;s question about uniqueness is a good one.

Comment: Is "K" your partition key? How k is related to partitioning key? Do you have the same k values in different partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Partition wise joins require equipartition both tables on their join keys, or reference partitioning by join keys, so looks like you haven't specified partition key in join predicates, ie you need to add join predicates by your partition keys or your table must be partitioned by hash(k)

Answer (score 0):

The most probable explanation of the difference is that the tables are **not** partitioned on the column `K`.

Here a simple demonstration

```
CREATE TABLE tab
     (id NUMBER,
      k NUMBER)
PARTITION BY HASH (id)
PARTITIONS 2; 

CREATE TABLE tab1
     (id NUMBER,
      k NUMBER)
PARTITION BY HASH (id)
PARTITIONS 2; 

insert into tab (id,k) values(1,0);
insert into tab (id,k) values(2,1);

insert into tab1 (id,k) values(1,1);
insert into tab1 (id,k) values(2,0);
```

A join of the two tables return two rows as follows

```
select * 
from tab
join tab1 
on tab.k = tab1.k;

        ID          K         ID          K
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          0          2          0
         2          1          1          1
```

But if you join partition by partition you get *no rows* as there corresponding `K` values are in different partitions (see the different columns `ID`)

If the table **is partitioned on `K`** it is safer to use the [partition extended names](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements009.htm#SQLRF51143) (instead of partition names) to reference single partitions in the join. See example below for the key `1`

```
select * 
from tab partition for(1)
join tab1 partition for(1)
on tab.k = tab1.k;
```

Of course the tricky part is to get the *proper values for the `for` clause* to reference all partition, which is not trivial as it is Oracle internal mechanism. See some hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49570422/4808122)

Comment: Thnq all..this got resolved ..the issue was because of the partition order ..I was joining the wrong combination of partition from both tables going by names ,but the partition order was different..

Comment: Ha Ha @laxmikanthb, good point when the partition names doesn't match in order. I added a notion of the partition extended names to avoid this problem