# Oracle SELECT PARTITION syntax with Range Scan

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

Say you have a hash partitioned table with a local index like this:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    bar NUMBER,
    baz NUMBER,
    a NUMBER
)
PARTITION BY HASH (bar) (
    PARTITION H0, 
    PARTITION H1
);

-- LOCAL index
CREATE INDEX foo_n1 ON foo (baz, a) LOCAL;
```

Assume you know in advance which partition some data is in, and would like to query the table with a known value for `baz` (which is locally indexed).

Is there any real benefit from querying a direct partition (`FROM foo PARTITION (H0)`):

```
SELECT *
FROM foo PARTITION (H0)
WHERE 1=1
    AND baz = 1234
```

Versus just querying all partitions `FROM foo`:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE 1=1
    AND baz = 1234
```

?

I would think not.

Filtering on `BAZ = 1234` will result in a range scan over the btree index, which will find the first entry of `1234` in O(log n) time; all other entries will be adjacent and it is just a matter of navigating through them. The main work is finding the first entry in the index.

Even if you had 64 partitions, each with a million rows, for a grand total of 64 million rows, the difference between `log(64,000,000)` and `log(1,000,000)` to find the first entry of `1234` appears pretty immaterial.

Edit: as @astentx mentioned, not using the PARTITION syntax will result in `64 * log(1,000,000)`, while using PARTITION should result in `log(1,000,000)`. Assuming base 10, this is a difference of 384 vs 6 comparisons, which is a lot bigger than my previous estimation.

---

It seems to me that the direct partition query would only be significant for full fast index scans and index skip scans, because these scans take O(n) to find the first entry in the index, so minimizing the total row count would have a larger material effect. It would likewise help for full table scans for the same reasoning. However I can't see how this would help for range scans and unique scans.

Is this correct?

---

Additionally, I'm not sure a relatively large deduction in the number of comparisons while searching an index will have a significant affect most of the time. My guess is that the query will spend most of its time doing table access for each rowid that is returned from the index, and that the 364 vs 6 comparisons to look up the correct item in the index would take up a relatively small amount of time. I have not tested it however.

Comment: How can you know the partition when you have a HASH partition?

Comment: Why do you estimate the second query with `O(log(64000000))` and not with `64O(log(1000000))`? As of definition: *In a local index, all keys in a particular index partition refer only to rows stored in a single underlying table partition*, so DBMS need to scan every partition to find the particular key to start with. Also you can compare execution plans of both the queries to see this difference. And as mentioned above, you need to use `partition for` instead of partition name for hash partitioned table (since you do not know the name upfront).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49570422/4808122), this is also the answer for the OP @MatthewMoisen *by specifying the partition* you save basically one call of `ora_hash()` function ...

Comment: log(64,000,000) is it difficulty using global index?

Comment: @astentx I think you are right and should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: @astentx You are right; it should be 64 * log(1,000,000). Assuming natural log, `64 * log(1,000,000) == 384`, while `log(1,000,000) == 6`. So 384 vs 6 comparisons before we find the first `baz = 1234` in the index. However I'm not certain if this results in a significant difference in query time - I have not tested a huge query. For example, would the actual table access for each rowid that needs to be returned from this query overwhelm any savings in time from 384 vs 6 comparisons?